# Set stylesheet for private member of a QWidget

Tags: c++, qt, private, qstylesheet

I've a class like the following one:

```
class BigButton : public QWidget {

  Q_OBJECT

public:

  BigButton(QWidget* parent = nullptr);
  virtual ~BigButton() = default;
  void setSvgImagePath(const QString& imagePath);
  void setLabel(const QString& label) override;

private:

  QLabel* m_label;
  QSvgWidget* m_svgImage;
  QPushButton* m_button;
};
```

I want to create a stylesheet for my application that allows to set some properties (like the background color) of the private `QPushButton` member `m_button`, but not other `QPushButton` around my GUI.

I've seen how to set [stylesheet for subclasses](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-syntax.html), but I cannot find a way to set the stylesheet for the specific private member of a class. Is there a way to achieve it?

Comment: why do not you set an objectname?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested by eyllanesc, [set an object name](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#objectName-prop) to your button, and use the [ID selector](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-syntax.html) in your stylesheet:

```
m_button->setObjectName("myButton");
```

---

```
widget->setStyleSheet("QPushButton#myButton{...}");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 m_button->setStyleSheet(m_button->styleSheet().append("background-color: rgb(9, 91, 255);"));
```

This will set the background color only for m_button

Comment: That's correct but I want to set it by composition. I've a class that contains the button, and I want to set the stylesheet for that class, in order to change the button automatically.